# Vbscript - move characters to the right from a comma character

Tags: vb.net, string, vbscript

This is probably a quick one. But I've got this string which looks like this:

```
Gabriel, Peter
```

And I want this string to look like this:

```
Peter Gabriel
```

I know about the replace and split functions, but I'm not sure how I can make this as simple as possible without messing around too much?

Edit: I actually fixed it by messing around a little. Here's the code

```
    Dim strDisplayName as string
    strDisplayName = "Gabriel, Peter"
    Dim strTemp() As String
    strTemp = Split(strDisplayName, ",")
    strTemp(1) = Replace(strTemp(1), " ", "")
    strDisplayName = strTemp(1) & " " & strTemp(0)
```

It might not be the most elegant solution, but atleast I can tell what's going on :p

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not an edit to your question. Then accept an answer (perhaps your own) to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Dim YourString As String = "Gabriel, Peter"

Dim Temp() As String = Split(YourString, ", ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)

Dim Result As String = Temp(1) & " " & Temp(0)

'now Result = "Peter Gabriel"
```

**Note:** This solution has been tested OK in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this because I am on a mac, but here is how I guess it will work

```
dim fullname as string = "Gabriel, Peter"

dim order_name as string = fullname.substring(indexof(", ")+1) & " " & fullname.substring(1,indexof(","))

msgbox order_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim strDisplayName As String = "Gabriel, Peter"
    Dim strTemp() As String = Split(strDisplayName, ",")
    Array.Reverse(strTemp)
    Dim PersonName As String = Join(strTemp, " ")
```

This should work in VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you know the comma is present:

```
aParts = split(oldvalue, ",")
newvalue = trim(aPart(1)) & " " & trim(aPart(0))
```

You could probably do it all on one line and not need the intermediate array (or maybe not, my vbscript is a little rusty) but that would mean calling split twice so would likely be less efficient anyway.

Or without split, just use basic string functions:

```
newvalue = trim(mid(oldvalue, instr(oldvalue,",")+1) & " " & trim(mid(oldvalue, instr(oldvalue,",")-1)
```

<sup>**Edit:** I've just noticed you've tagged the question vb.net as well as vbscript. The above is vbscript, I know little of vb.net...</sup>